# How to write code for a fragment class in Tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout in my project with each having it's own fragments now the tab layout is working fine. My problem is how can I access the elements like edit text values and other from the fragments I'm totally confused of that. Kindly help me in this issue I browsed a lot videos in YouTube but every video shows how to create a fragment and there aren't showing what I need.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jQv0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must firstly make the the MainActivity's component reference variable public.

e.g

```
public EditBox mEditBox
```

To get this variable in your fragments, simply type:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).mEditBox
```

So to get the EditBoxes text value you would type

```
String value = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mEditBox.getText().ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks for that I just made a onViewcreate method inside the fragment class and now it works as I thought. Thanks a lot for taking time to answer this question